# add rewrite rule in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, url-rewriting, seo, rules

I have added this code to `functions.php` file

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%country%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^Location/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=10924&country=$matches[1]','top');
}

function register_custom_query_vars( $vars) {

    array_push($vars , 'country'); 
    return $vars;
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'register_custom_query_vars' , 1 );
add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10 ,0 );
```

but I still have 404 error even after flushing the rules.
My page name is Location and the page_id is 10924
I need this URL `Location/?country=us` to be like that `Location/us`

any help?

Answer (score 0):

I think, that better way for rewrite rules is type it to .htaccess file. You can find it in root of your FTP files with web.

You can see more in documentation at [Wordpress site](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess)

Comment: thank you for your response. I tried that, but it gave me Too_many_redirects error I have added this line https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gf8_WLtsU8z0qcpjWhp_ZB8726nHton-/view?usp=sharing